# Trouble setting up LDAPS for login in Sonarqube Docker container

Tags: docker, ldap, sonarqube

I am running Sonarqube in a docker container using the default image from docker hub.  Sonarqube is working fine.  I am now working on using LDAPS for system login and can't seem to get it to work.  I created a centos:latest container and have sonarqube running there.  I did this so I could have ldapsearch, vim, telnet, update-ca, etc.  I used openssl to add the server certificate.  I tested with ldapsearch and the following is successful:

```
[root@bf9accb5647d linux-x86-64]# ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://dir.example.com -b "dc=example,dc=com" -D "uid=svcSonar,ou=SvcAccts,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com" -W '(uid=usernamehere)' cn
Enter LDAP Password: ******
dn: uid=usernamehere,ou=Users,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
cn: User Name
```

Here is my relevant ldap configuration in sonar.properties:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldaps://dir.example.com
ldap.bindDN=uid=svcSonar,ou=SvcAccts,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
ldap.bindPassword=mypassword
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=Users,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(uid={login})
```

Here is the relevant sonar.log entries with TRACE and DEBUG on:

```
2016.04.15 16:32:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin LDAP / 1.5.1 / 8960e08512a3d3ec4d9cf16c4c2c95017b5b7ec5
2016.04.15 20:19:07 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2016.04.15 20:19:07 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=ou=Users,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com, request=(uid={0}), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}
2016.04.15 20:19:07 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldaps://dir.example.com, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
2016.04.15 20:19:07 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldaps://dir.example.com: OK
2016.04.15 20:19:07 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
.
.
.
2016.04.15 20:26:55 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] Requesting details for user usernamehere
2016.04.15 20:26:55 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapSearch] Search: LdapSearch{baseDn=ou=Users,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com, scope=s
ubtree, request=(uid={0}), parameters=[usernamehere], attributes=[mail, cn]}
2016.04.15 20:26:55 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldaps://di
r.example.com, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.na
ming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
2016.04.15 20:26:55 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] User usernamehere not found in <default>
```

I did the following for the certificate:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -connect server:port -prexit 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p' > ldap.pem
update-ca-trust force-enable
cp ldap.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract
```

I also used the keytool to add the ldap.pem to the java cacerts for the jre being using by Sonarqube.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | sudo tee /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/<server>.crt`? (replacing `<server>` and `<port>` with the right values). So copying the cert as `<server>.crt` (not `ldap.pem`). Then `update-ca-trust`.

Comment: I tried to above and the same result:  [root@bf9accb5647d anchors]# ls -ltr
total 8  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3286 Apr 15 16:37 ldap.crt  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1643 Apr 18 13:59 dir.example.com.crt  
[root@bf9accb5647d anchors]# update-ca-trust force-enable  
[root@bf9accb5647d anchors]# update-ca-trust extract

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` on that system?

Comment: No.  ca-bundle.crt and ca-bundle.trust.crt

Comment: I also changed the disabledAlgorithms in the java.security file in the jre lib to include  MD5withRSA as OpenSSL returns the following:  Signature algorithm name: MD5withRSA
         Version: 3

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I needed to change ldap.bindDN to ldap.bindDn. :)